# Issues in merging branches

Tags: svn

We have two branches.  One is a Release Branch (RB) taken from the trunk.  The other is a Feature Branch (FB) taken from RB.

We now would like to merge FB back to RB.  Ultimately, RB will be merged back to trunk.

I tried to do this with a re-integrate merge, but got the following error:

```
svn: Cannot reintegrate from 'url://feature-branch' yet:
Some revisions have been merged under it that have not been merged
into the reintegration target; merge them first, then retry.
```

Some questions:

1. Should I be using a re-integrate merge to merge FB into RB or some other method?
2. Should I ensure that RB is merged into FB before merging FB back to RB?
3. What is likely causing the above error?

This is with Subversion 1.5

Many thanks

Comment: I think I've seen this error before - did you by any chance merge changes from the trunk into the feature branch that aren't in the RB or vice versa?

Comment: No we haven't done this, in fact so far there have been no merges from the trunk or RB to FB, and this could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had very similar problems myself before and here's how I solved them:

1. Firstly, ensure both branches are
   updated from the trunk
2. Do a cleanup
3. Ensure FB is updated from RB and fix up any conflicts
4. Do a cleanup
5. Merge FB into RB and fix up any
   conflicts
6. Do a cleanup
7. Merge RB back to the trunk and fix
   up and conflicts

Comment: thanks - presumably you are not doing a 'reintegrate' merge at any point with these merges?  I'm confused as to whether the reintegrate is necessary - I thought it was for a merge from a branch back to a main line of development

Comment: I usually stay away from the reintegration merge. I've found it more trouble that it's worth to be honest. It may be a slight lack of education on my part but this is the way I've found the simplest and quickest way to get the job done.